# Firebase deployment error using Inline-Editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up a simple Google Cloud Function with the following code:

index.js:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.updateLastMessage = functions.database.ref("/messages/{chatID}/{messageID}").onWrite(event => {
  console.log("New Message received")
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "updateLastMessage",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.1",
    "actions-on-google": "^1.0.7",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

When I try to deploy it, I get the following error:

```
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function.
    at init (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/config.js:51:15)
    at Object.config (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/config.js:29:9)
    at Object.ref (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/database.js:58:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:3:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
```

It tells me to update the Firebase CLI, although I am not even using them, I am using the Inline-Editor. What should I do?

Comment: To deploy the code you run `firebase deploy`, which is an invocation on the Firebase CLI. I'd focus on the "Is there a syntax error in your code?" bit.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, I don't use the Firebase CLI, I use the online version. And I don't find a syntax error, even though there has to be one.

Comment: What online version are you referring to? I don't know of any online editor for Cloud Functions on Firebase. Can you provide a link or a screenshot?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This thing: https://imgur.com/a/xBerU https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/add

Comment: Ah... I never could successfully edit Firebase deployed function code with that. Sorry I can't be of more use.

Comment: Where did you see using Cloud Functions for Firebase on this CLI? The only documentation I found was for Google Cloud Functions https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console

Comment: cloud functions and firebase functions I think similar but different things. As you can see from the create function form there is no "Database Triggered" option which means your code is not good for this type of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to work around this error. I had some Cloud Functions already deployed from the Firebase CLI. When I tried to create a new one from the Webinterface, the error threw. Apparently you can only have Cloud Functions working together from the same type of CLI, you can't combine them. To fix the error, I had to redeploy them all using the console.